# Why can't I open SQL Developer when I have Java 10 installed?

Tags: java, sqldeveloper

In my Mac terminal:

```
$ javac -version
javac 10.0.1
```

I open SQL Developer and get this dialog:

> SQL Developer requires a minimum of Java 8.  Java 8 can be downloaded
>   from:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/

[image: The dialog image]

How do I get SQL developer to work?

Comment: Could be a simple system variable path issue.

Comment: I download java sdk 8 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and now sql developer works

Comment: maybe you had OpenJDK, while OracleJDK was required? (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714163/2147927) comment)

Comment: @Line Sorry my SQL developer works now and I don't remember what I did to fix it. I should have posted my solution when I fixed it. I will just leave this question open if other people encounter same issue

Answer (score 5):

If you don't still want to keep java 10, the fix is easy

```
vi /Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh
```

Change the second line:

From:

```
TMP_PATH=`/usr/libexec/java_home -F -v 9`
```

To

```
TMP_PATH=`/usr/libexec/java_home -F -v 10`
```

Comment: You deserve more likes. Great fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Installed SQL Developer 18.2.0.183 with JDK 10.0.1 and had this message:

> Found /usr/java/jdk-10.0.1/bin/java/bin/java to run this product, and
>   the major version of this Java is 10.The mandatory minimum major
>   version to run this product is 1.8.

Once I removed the 10.0.1 version and installed the 1.8.0_172 version it worked fine.